# how to get free ip in range 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.x.255 with golang?

Tags: go

I want to get the computer's free local IP address from range of addresses.
net.LookupHost will return only 127.0.0.1 or public ip addresses.

net.LookupHost(name)

Comment: All localhost addresses are the same, you can pick anyone you want and it will all be the same as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A network has many addresses. A CIDR has many addresses. But a network interface only have one, so it seems you are trying to assign virtual network interfaces with other addresses in the lookback range. Is that even possible? I guess I thought that was always selected by the kernel when the device came up.

Comment: @theherk, "A network interface only have one [address]" is incorrect. One can assign many addresses to a single network interface.

Comment: elaborate, current question lacks sense.

Comment: @theherk, you can assign any number of addresses of any family to an interface (with some exceptions, such as point-to-point type interfaces where multiple addresses don't make sense).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function below can help you:

```
  func getLocalhostIP() string {
        netInterfaces, err := net.Interfaces()
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf("net.Interfaces failed, err:", err)
            return ""
        }
    
        for i := 0; i < len(netInterfaces); i++ {
            if (netInterfaces[i].Flags & net.FlagUp) != 0 {
                addrs, _ := netInterfaces[i].Addrs()
    
                for _, address := range addrs {
                    if ipnet, ok := address.(*net.IPNet); ok && !ipnet.IP.IsLoopback() {
                        if ipnet.IP.To4() != nil {
                            return ipnet.IP.String()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
```